# Extract List<int> with positions from indexOf from string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I want to get IndexOf some "Text" and their positions from string

```
string myString = "some text some text some text text text text";
int countOfText = myString.Select((c, i) => myString.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.StartsWith("some"));
```

in code above I obtain count of "some", how to get List with their positions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex.Matches(input,@"\bsome\b")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(x=>x.Index);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient approach is using [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224424(v=vs.110).aspx) in a loop with the start index:

```
List<int> positions = new List<int>();
int pos = myString.IndexOf("some", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
while (pos >= 0)
{
    positions.Add(pos);
    pos = myString.IndexOf("some", pos + "some".Length, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Result: `0, 10, 20`

I have used `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` to demonstrate case insensitive comparison. You don't need it if `"Some"` should not *count*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Regex (@Anirudha answer) or with linq:

```
string myString = "some text some text some text text text text";
var res = myString
    .Select((c, i) => new { txt = myString.Substring(i), idx = i })
    .Where(sub => sub.txt.StartsWith("some"))
    .Select(a => a.idx).ToList();
```

(this seem to be overkill though, I would prefer the regex version myself)

Comment: This loops every character, i'd prefer [`String.IndexOf(string, startIndex)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224424(v=vs.110).aspx) to search only the relevant part of it. It also creates an anonymous type and a new string for every character.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes. that's why I said it's overkill :) I only demonstrated it could be done with linq, based on the code the OP already has. I wonder if a linq solution that uses IndexOf can be created?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a extension method that helped me out that way. i would use this in case you want to gather indexes multiple times in your code.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string searchstring)
{
    int minIndex = str.IndexOf(searchstring);
    while (minIndex != -1)
    {
        yield return minIndex;
        minIndex = str.IndexOf(searchstring, minIndex + searchstring.Length);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
string myString = "some text some text some text text text text";
List<int> Result = myString.AllIndexesOf("some");
```